# Add two NSJSONSerialization objects to a singular NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsjsonserialization

I have one `NSMutableArray` that a `UITableView` pulls data from. I'd like to add two `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data]` to this singular array. Doing the following only replaces the information previously added to the array, I want to add the new request below.

```
jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the NSMutableArray documentation? There *are* methods to add the objects from a second array.

Comment: Indeed, but when I use `[jsonArray addObject:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]];` it shows as (null) with no objects in the array.

Comment: That probably means that `jsonArray` is not alloc/inited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *json1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 ...];
if (json1 != nil) {
    [jsonArray addObjectsFromArray:json1];
} else {
    // JSON error in data1
}

NSArray *json2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data2 ...];
if (json2 != nil) {
    [jsonArray addObjectsFromArray:json2];
} else {
    // JSON error in data2
}
```